# Why does my form not display properly on iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, html, forms, ipad, adobe-indesign

I am using a form within an iPad edition of a publication, and when I select the text field of the form, it puts a duplicate form on top of the first form (see [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGKHB.png)). Does anyone know why this might be happening? If it helps, this is an HTML snippet in InDesign CS6. The code works fine in a browser. Any ideas why this code isn't working?

```
<div align="center" style="background-color: transparent;">
<div style="width:100%; background-color: transparent;">
<form name="ccoptin" action="http://visitor.r20.constantcontact.com/d.jsp"
target="_blank" method="post" style="margin-bottom:3;">
<input type="text" name="ea" size="20" value="" style="font-family: Gotham, 
'Helvetica  Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; border:1px solid 
#999999;">
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit" class="submit"  style="font-family: 
Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px;">
<input type="hidden" name="llr" value="cgw6xxdab">
<input type="hidden" name="m" value="1103529695426">
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="oi">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might be a strange request, but do you have a screenshot from chrome, or firefox that we can see? Also, any CSS would be helpful

Comment: No CSS, just the inline styles you see there. This is a ![screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/2Nyu5Jn.png) from Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the following code and take out the CSS?

```
<meta name="viewport" id="iphone-viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
```

Or is there a reason why you are using CSS?